# background formatting in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report in Vs 2010.
I'm Trying to format the background of a Column Based on data values.
Using this code only the first condition Woks because I tried to switch the if conditions and again only the first condition works.

```html
IF {TBM_Report_qry.DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.tbm} then RGB(234,234,234)
else
IF {TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.Reqired} then RGB(234,234,234)
else
IF {TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close}<={TBM_Report_qry.clse_Diff} then RGB(234,234,234)
```

**TBM_Report_qry.DiF** is the number of weeks being calculated in a Access Query (the number of weeks from the current Date and the date the order needs to be measured.)**{TBM_Report_qry.tbm}** is the time number of weeks allowed to process the order.
**{TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF}**  (the number of weeks from the current Date and the date the order needs to be ready for production. Only special orders will have a date in this field.)
**{TBM_Report_qry.Reqired}** is a number (weeks) allowed.**{TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close}** the number of weeks the order needs to be ready for delivery **{TBM_Report_qry.clse_Diff}** is a number of weeks to be compared.
So any or all these conditions could be tue or none.
these are being formatted on the Address Column.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Siva and T_G For trying.
I have solved by Checking for null values.
Here is My working Formula.

```html
IF Not ISNULL({TBM_Report_qry.DiF}) AND {TBM_Report_qry.DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.tbm} then RGB(234,234,234)
IF Not ISNULL({TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF})AND{TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.Reqired} then RGB(234,234,234) 
else
IF  Not ISNULL({TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close})AND {TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close}<={TBM_Report_qry.clse_Diff} then RGB(234,234,234) 
else   crNoColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
IF {TBM_Report_qry.DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.tbm} then RGB(234,234,234)
else
(
    IF {TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.Reqired} 
    then RGB(234,234,234)
    else 
    (
       IF {TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close}<={TBM_Report_qry.clse_Diff} 
       then RGB(234,234,234) 
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks T_G for your reply but it still doesn't work only the first If gets executed

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
IF {TBM_Report_qry.DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.tbm} or
   {TBM_Report_qry.inproduction_DiF}<={TBM_Report_qry.Reqired} or
   {TBM_Report_qry.DiF_Close}<={TBM_Report_qry.clse_Diff} 
then 
RGB(234,234,234)
```

Comment: Thanks Siva but sill only the first If is formating

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with the record from database.. can you post how the record looks like because every time your first condition is getting true.